# zimbra запретить отправку исходящих писем

Tags: postfix, zimbra

Имеется zimbra 8.7.0. Нужно настроить ограничения на отправку исходящих писем на публичные домены (mail.ru, gmail.com и подобные) с некоторых корпоративных ящиков. 
Белый список я осилил (когда пользователям запрещено отправлять на любые домены, кроме разрешенных), но вводить 100500 адресов почты в этот список - безумие.

Что уже пробовал сделать: добавил параметр `<key name="postfix_transport_maps">
<value>hash:/opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_transport, proxy:ldap:/opt/zimbra/conf/ldap-transport.cf</value> </key>` в файл /opt/zimbra/conf/localconfig.xml

Менял параметры postfix'a: `postconf -e "smtpd_recipient_restrictions=check_recipient_access lmdb:/opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_recipient_access, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unlisted_recipient, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_client_hostname, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject"`
Вроде как это должно работать, но после рестарта zmmta - данный параметр вновь принимает прежнее значение.
postmap postfix_recipient_access с вписанными в него доменами mail.ru REJECT и gmail.com REJECT внёс. Куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Всё, сам нашел. Забыл, что я когда-то уже вносил изменения в /opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_check_recipient_access.cf в виде check_recipient_access lmdb:/opt/zimbra/conf/local_domains, reject.
Поменял на check_recipient_access lmdb:/opt/zimbra/conf/local_domains, permit - и всё стало как надо.